# Conditional update in elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to add a flag with value 2 where the "codigoTema" = 2

The truth is, I'm new to elasticsearch. I would appreciate your help.

I attach my current code. Maybe this is bad because I'm new to this

thank you very much

```
  POST /lecordonbleu_des/documentos/_update_by_query
    {
        "script": "ctx._source.flag =   2",
        "query": {
            "query_string" : {
                "fields" : ["codigoTema"],
                "query" : "2"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What response do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following syntax for the script:

```
POST /lecordonbleu_des/documentos/_update_by_query
{
  "script" : 
    {
      "inline": "ctx._source.flag = 2",
      "lang": "painless"
    },
  "query": {
     "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["codigoTema"],
        "query" : "2"
      }
   }
}
```